# Rancher : Failed to find rancher-agent container

Tags: docker, rancher

Im trying to create a new host (DigitalOccean) using rancher UI, every thing was Good but at the end i got this error :

```
"Failed to find rancher-agent container"
```

Logs :

```
time="2017-07-20T09:55:57Z" level=info msg="stdout: Running pre-create checks..." resourceId: =1ph86 service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:55:58Z" level=info msg="stdout: Creating machine..." resourceId: =1ph86 service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:55:58Z" level=info msg="stdout: (oo) Creating SSH key..." resourceId: =1ph86 service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:55:59Z" level=info msg="stdout: (oo) Creating Digital Ocean droplet..." resourceId: =1ph86 service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:56:00Z" level=info msg="stdout: (oo) Waiting for IP address to be assigned to the Droplet..." resourceId: =1ph86 service=gms
...
time="2017-07-20T09:57:31Z" level=info msg="pulling rancher/agent:v1.2.5 image." service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:57:43Z" level=info msg="Container created for machine" containerId=5bef89f75de6fc256f0adbe1cc9c7138292aaa4bd7d8446546d208823cd8b22f machineId=1ph86 resourceId=1ph86 service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:58:46Z" level=error msg="Failed to find rancher-agent container" machineId=1ph86 resourceId=1ph86 service=gms 
time="2017-07-20T09:58:46Z" level=error msg="Error processing event" err="Failed to find rancher-agent container" eventId=08649e06-ddcd-445d-b120-91c0e7498835 eventName="physicalhost.bootstrap;handler=goMachineService" resourceId=1ph86
```

any idea ?

Answer (score -1):

1. You should make sure that the NEW HOST has the Docker Image of `rancher/agent:v1.2.5`.

By using the command below:

```
# sudo docker images|grep rancher/agent
rancher/agent  v1.2.2  6777bc8a1147  3 months ago  233.7 MB
```

If the host does not has the docker image, get it by using `sudo docker pull rancher/agent:v1.2.5`

2. Then checking the container logs of `rancher agent`.

By using the command below:

```
# sudo docker ps -a |grep rancher/agent
1c03d064165c  rancher/agent:v1.2.2  "/run.sh run"  5 days ago  Up 5 days  rancher-agent

# sudo docker logs 1c03d064165c
```

- If you find that container, even its status is `Exited\Created\Dead`, read its logs carefully and find the solutions of that BUG by asking for Google\Github;
- IF you can NOT find that container, read the file of `docker-compose.yml` and `rancher-compose.yml`, make sure that you get **the right docker image**, include **the right image version**.